# angular unable to read JSON

Tags: angularjs, json, drupal

This json coming from [JSON Create URL](http://localhost/santa/santaws_resources/santaws_resources)

http://localhost/santa/santaws_resources/santaws_resources

> {"records":[{"Name":"8","Country":""},{"Name":"2","Country":"Bharanikumar"},{"Name":"7","Country":"fasdf"},{"Name":"5","Country":"Reach
>   Us"},{"Name":"6","Country":"ss"},{"Name":"10","Country":"ssss"},{"Name":"1","Country":"test"},{"Name":"9","Country":"test"},{"Name":"3","Country":"test
>   Math question *"},{"Name":"4","Country":"This is testing ajax"}]}

Web service written in DRUPAL - service module.

Angular unable to read the above JSON URL, please let me know root cause for this problem.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <!--
    To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
    To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
    and open the template in the editor.
    -->
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>TODO supply a title</title>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl"> 
                <ul>
                  <li ng-repeat="x in myData">
                    {{ x.Name + ', ' + x.Country }}
                  </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <script>
            var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
            app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
              $http.get("http://localhost/santa/santaws_resources/santaws_resources").then(function (response) {
                  $scope.myData = response.data.records;
              });
            });
            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

[image: service URL not loaded]

Attached, updated one

[image]

Comment: I think you should look at console..it must have any information about what is failing..

Comment: i checked console, no JS error. any specific tab in console i have to look ?

Comment: inspect actual ajax request in network tab

Comment: Hi @PankajParkar attached network tab, service URL not loaded, is there any place, i have make select for allow orgin anything ?

Comment: select All in the bottom tab. Right now you are filtering only HTML requests.

Comment: @Bharanikumar your ajax call is not showing in the network tab..you need to select `ALL` option in network tab..instead of `HTML` which is currently being selected

Comment: yes @PankajParkar attached updated screen shot, response is empty

Comment: Access-Control-Allow-Orig.. missing in my tab, so another application unable to consume the service, plz confirm

Answer (score 0):

All your codes are doing well. I think you are either calling the wrong json file from $http.get() 
Check this for reference : [AngularJS $http](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_http.asp)

Comment: bro this code only i took, to test program i just simulated same like this program service URL json output. but still proablem, is there any stuff i have to do " Allows Cross-origin resource sharing. "

Comment: If you have CORS error then it should give error on your console. If there is no any error as your are saying.. so it's not the CORS issue

Comment: what is the actual suck i don't understand in my program

Comment: look on the headers in the screen shot, please confirm Content-Type 
application/json or Content-Type 
text/html; charset=UTF-8

Comment: Where you have put your html file..? In the same domain...? 
If you have put it on the same domain then there is no any cors issue.
I haven't work with durpal web services. If you have the web service and the client html code is running on different domain then you have to allow cors on the web service portion. 
You can check this link to allow cors on the web service 
https://www.drupal.org/node/1869548

Comment: i used w3school sample program, i just replaced the w3school api to mine one, weschool api working fine, but mine is not working inside html, angular,   but when i paste the api url in browser rest api plugin, i can able to see the json formatted string.

Comment: It should Be cors issue.. you just try 
"Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *" 
on your web api method/class that is serving the json content.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100940/discussion-between-bharanikumar-and-biswajit-panday).

Comment: in crhome: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://127.1.0.1/santa/santaws_resources/santaws_resources.json. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.

Answer (score 0):

step 1 and step 2 solved the issue
step 1
[image: step1]

step 2
[image: step 2]